# Double segue behavior when user authorizes location use

Tags: ios, swift, segue, cllocationmanager

In my iOS application I’m requesting the user’s permission to obtain the device’s location. On my main ViewController I have a navigation bar button that when tapped, it will ask the user for permission for when in use. If the user taps OK, it will then be send to the view controller that displays the local data. If the user taps Cancel then nothing happens. I also have a pop up for when and if the user taps again on the location button to be redirected to the settings to authorize location use if previously cancelled.

The app works as I intended in the simulator but when used on a device, when the user taps OK to allow location use, it segues to the local View Controller but it does so 2 or 3 times consecutively.

The segue goes from the main view controller to the local view controller and it requests permissions from the button tap using an IBAction.

The location information is obtained in the main view controller and passed to the local controller. The local controller displays everything as it is intended.

How can I prevent this double or triple segue to the same View Controller?

Below is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toLocal" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! LocalViewController
        destination.latitude = latitude
        destination.longitude = longitude
    }
}

//MARK: - Location Manager Methods
@IBAction func LocationNavBarItemWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    }

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .restricted, .denied:
        showLocationDisabledPopUp()
        return
    case .notDetermined:
        // Request Access
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .authorizedAlways:
        print("Do Nothing: authorizedAlways")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLocal", sender: nil)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("LocationManager failed with error \(error)")
}

private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
        showLocationDisabledPopUp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **superpuccio** already stated the main issue is that the `didUpdateLocations` delegate function is called multiple times. I also do not know why you are checking the `authorizationStatus` in the `didUpdateLocations` function since at that point it is already clear that the user allowed location access. In my opinion the function should look something like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // check for a location that suits your needs
    guard let location = locations.last, location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 else { return }

    // prevent the manager from updating the location and sending more location events
    manager.delegate = nil
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // update the local variables
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
    longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

    // perform the segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLocal", sender: nil)
}
```

Since there are some more issues like starting location updates before knowing the actual authorization status I'll provide a full solution like I'd do it. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees?
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees?

    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        return locationManager
    }()

    @IBAction func getLocation(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        checkAuthorizationStatus()
    }

    private func checkAuthorizationStatus(_ status: CLAuthorizationStatus? = nil) {
        switch status ?? CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            showLocationDisabledPopUp()
        }
    }

    func showLocationDisabledPopUp() {
        // your popup code
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // your segue code
    }

}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkAuthorizationStatus(status)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last, location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 else { return }

        manager.delegate = nil
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLocal", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are performing a segue in

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

that can be fired multiple times (each time a new location comes from the `CLLocationManager`). There are several ways to solve this, but in order to make you change as little as possible I suggest this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    }

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .restricted, .denied:
        showLocationDisabledPopUp()
        return
    case .notDetermined:
        // Request Access
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .authorizedAlways:
        print("Do Nothing: authorizedAlways")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        //-- MODIFIED HERE --
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager = nil
        Dispatch.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLocal", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helps, otherwise we can change a little more your code to solve this simple issue.

EDIT: just so you know: it would be better to perform the segue in

```
private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

when the status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse` depending on your needs.

Comment: I do not think that `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is the better place to perform the segue since at that point there might be no location yet.

Comment: You are right, but it's the point where Jose can be sure that the user has accepted the location permission request. So he can go to the second controller and start "firing" locations there. There's no need to start updating location on the main controller, the logic can be splitted in two: in the main controller just ask for permissions, in the second one start firing locations and show them to the user.

Comment: But if I understand him correctly the main view controller is responsible for fetching the location and passing it to the detail right now.

Comment: In that case you're right. I had understood that Jose was using the first location retrieved from CLLocationManager to say something like: "ok, a location has come, so all the system is up and running and I can go ahead".